# How to use Canvas with a render mode of Screen Space of Main Camera to a Render Texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use the rendered game view of a canvas onto a Rendered texture so I could create a minimap of the specific screen, I dont know how to get the rendered texture of my canvas. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Just plug a RenderTexture asset into the Camera? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

Comment: No that wouldnt work, I tried that even before asking, What is needed I think is getting the rendered texture on the main camera then passing it to another camera then render the image somewhere.

Camera Main -> Camera Two -> Rendered Texture. Because Camera two would be link to the Zoom or pointer of the mouse